# What does concurrent request and simultaneous connections mean for SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection, signalr

I know it's not special for SignalR, but since I was quite puzzled when I read some documents in SignalR [site](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance), maybe use SignalR would be suitable example.

For server side, there is some concept over **Max concurrent requests per application**

In SignalR, how could I reach the limit, I have to open 5000 client or something?

For client side, I know each browser has some limitation about **Max Connections**, can anyone explain this concept for me, simply tell me how can I reach the limit. And maybe use SignalR is a good example and easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server side : Max concurrent requests is configurable in IIS see [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance) so you can lower it to one , and try to connect with 2 clients.

For client side , there are many available client (.net, java, java script) on many browsers/platform you can start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)